# Is there any Scrum template process for TFS except than SfTS?

Tags: tfs, scrum, tfs-process-template

I'm going to do Scrum in VSTS (TFS 2010). I know about the famous process template [SfTS](http://scrumforteamsystem.com/) from scrumforteamsystem.com. But It seems to be too heavy. It includes Sprints, Team Sprints, Work Stream,... I'm wondering if there is any other Scrum template process for TFS 2010?

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,
Afshar

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found 2 myself:

1. [VSTS Scrum Process Template](http://vstsscrum.codeplex.com/)
2. eScrum

But it seems there is not any other Scrum template process for TFS.

Comment: Actually, I don't think either of those process templates are available for TFS 2010.  I'm not sure about #1, but eScrum has been discontinued - (see http://blogs.blackmarble.co.uk/blogs/rfennell/archive/2009/07/07/and-escrum-is-no-more.aspx)

Comment: @JamedsD, #1 were available in RC and now its final version is available for download. refer to its site.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft release in July 2010 the Visual Studio Scrum template.  You can download it here:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/59ac03e3-df99-4776-be39-1917cbfc5d8e

Use this template with [Urban Turtle](http://urbanturtle.com) and you have a great user experience. Discloser: I work with the Urban Turtle team. So do not take my words. Instead, read what Brian Harry, who is the Product Unit Manager for Team Foundation Server, said about Urban Turtle: "...awesome Scrum experience for TFS."

You can read Brian Harry's blog post [here](http://urbanturtle.com/awesome)

Answer (score 2):

The MSF Agile 5 process template that  comes with TFS has been Scrum-ified.  It is effective, though I'm often annoyed by the reports not being time boxed naturally to the current iteration like SfTS (kudo's to JamesD and his team).

That said, put it together with something like [UrbanTurtle](http://www.urbanturtle.com) or [Telerik Work Item Manager](http://www.telerik.com/products/tfsmanager-and-tfsdashboard.aspx) and you have a great day-to-day, tactical work tool.

Answer (score 2):

[Eylean Board](http://www.eylean.com/tfs?utm_source=website&utm_medium=forum&utm_campaign=DMStack) also offers a scrum process template for TFS 2010. 
With the two way integration, it is great that we can use the additional features effortlessly.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

*Full Disclosure: I work for EMC Consulting that develops the Scrum for Team System process template.*

The richer work item modelling available in TFS 2010 has enabled Scrum for Team System to support much more complex Scrum implementations ( http://microsoftpdc.com/Sessions/FT09 ), however, this does mean that the most straightforward scenario is more complicated to setup.

This was a principle reason for creating the Scrum Masters Workbench tool, as it provides a UI for visually configuring the artefacts you mention.  Additionally, this tool has a 'Quick Setup Mode' whose main purpose is to make it quick and easy to setup the required artefacts for the straightforward Scrum scenario (i.e. a single team).

See http://consultingblogs.emc.com/crispinparker/archive/2009/11/27/scrum-for-team-system-v3-beta-2-scrum-masters-workbench.aspx for information on the Scrum Masters Workbench.

Answer (score 0):

We use [EpiServer Scrum Dashboard](http://scrumdashboard.codeplex.com/) to manage our work items and backlog with TFS.

Answer (score 0):

There is the Scrum template in beta at [TFS 2010 Scrum](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/59ac03e3-df99-4776-be39-1917cbfc5d8e)
It is very light and a solid way to use scrum with TFS 2010. Although a Beta it is solid.